# ASP.NET Show Full Url in Browser for the Default Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, default-document

When I set the Default Document in IIS to display my Default page (`default.aspx`), and access it using the host header I implemented; it only shows the host header address and not the full page address in the browser.

For example:

Host header: `http://mysite`
IIS default document: `/PageContainer/default.aspx`

when I enter `http://mysite` through the browser; it opens the `http://mysite/PageContainer/default.aspx` but shows only the `http://mysite` address in the browser address bar.

How can I change it to show the full url like `http://mysite/PageContainer/default.aspx` in the browser address bar either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a redirect for

```
http://mysite --> http://mysite/PageContainer/default.aspx
```

Comment: Where do you add that recirect?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a default.aspx page in the root (i.e. `http://mysite/default.aspx`) with the following code and make 'default.aspx' the default document:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/PageContainer/default.aspx" />
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that I'm going to try. But @DaveDev's solution worked for me.